# how can i make an iframe (reddit embed post) responsive with width 100% and auto height

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, reddit

I am trying to display some reddit posts (as an iframe) in my website.

I want to make them responsive. with 100% width and height that will display all the content without overflow scroll.

when i'm trying to do so - the width is working fine but the height is shorten then what it should. and the post gets cutoff.

See this jsfiddle i created:
https://jsfiddle.net/qr1tzo3g/1/

html:

```
 <div id="container">
  <div id="body">
    <iframe id="reddit-embed" src="https://www.redditmedia.com/r/WhitePeopleTwitter/comments/ymji0q/oooooffff/?ref_source=embed&amp;ref=share&amp;embed=true" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups" style="border: none; width:100%; height:auto" scrolling="yes"></iframe>

    <iframe id="reddit-embed" src="https://www.redditmedia.com/r/funny/comments/ymkbo8/mountain_lion_wins_his_favourite_toy_in_the_shell/?ref_source=embed&amp;ref=share&amp;embed=true" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups" style="border: none; width:100%; height:auto" scrolling="yes"></iframe>

  </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
#container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#body{
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue?
Thanks you!

Comment: If you don't control both the iframe content and parent page, then there;s no way to do this in the browser. Cross-origin policy does not allow a parent to interact with a different hosted child. It's an security issue where a bad actor would be able to inject malicous thing on the child. IE rendering the paypal login screen as child and snoop on the details from the parent. If you search for 'Cross Domain iframe Resizing' you'll find other attempts, all will require some control on the embedded page.

Comment: @Lars yes, the iframe is a different site. Is it possible to get only info about the iframe child nodes? such as element.scrollHeight. and then i could do do manipulation and change the iframe height. this could work?

Comment: If the iframe is on a different domain, the site in the iframe needs to expose information to the parent via `postMessage`. When you *don't* have control over the iframe content, you *can not*.  It means the Child is protected from malicious embeds. Unless you're able the add code to the child, the child' content will be inaccessible to the parent.

Comment: when you say 'postMessage' that means they need to speak throw service workers? asking just for general knowledge

Comment: No, I'm talking about [window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). 
A postMessage triggered in the iframe will bubble up to the parent. The parent subscribes to listen for these messages. That means that the iframe can expose their size by sending messages to the parent, IE after the onLoad or after a resize. Again, you would need control of the iframe content in order to add the code that will send these postMessages for the parent to handle.

Comment: In your case, depending on how much effort you want to put into this. You could either, set a default size that approximately is the size of the iframe content OR use the reddit-api to pull in the data of a post, then render that in a view similar to how reddit would render it.